# R{raster} getValues(): error accessing values of large raster?

Tags: raster, r

I am getting the following, while extracting all values with:

> rs<-getValues(rster)

Error in getRasterData(con, offset = offs, region.dim = reg, band = object at data@band): long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:3308

```
rster
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 76740, 80200, 6154548000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 50, 50  (x, y)
extent      : -1888000, 2122000, -4847000, -1010000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=-18 +lat_2=-36 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=132 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : /data/her134/BA/GDA94albers/clum50m0314 
names       : clum50m0314 
values      : 100, 663  (min, max)
attributes  :
    ID  COUNT LU_CODEV7 LU_CODEV7N TERTIARY_V7
from: 100 540931     1.0.0        100  1.0.0 Conservation and natural environments
to  : 663   1755     6.6.3        663 6.6.3 Estuary/coastal waters - intensive use
                          SECONDARY_V7 PRIMARY_V7 CLASSES_18
1.0 Conservation and natural environments 1 Conservation and natural environments          1
            6.6 Estuary/coastal waters                                 6 Water         17
       C18_DESCRIPTION
Nature conservation (1.1)
           Water (6.0)
```

Using:
platform       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          1.0
year           2014
month          04
day            10
svn rev        65387
language       R
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance

raster version 2.2.31

Linux:
LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Release:    11
Codename:   n/a

I used to be able to handle this sized raster in earlier versions.

Any ideas of a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Just looks like memory issues, try getting blocks of rows instead, process them and replace the values.

```
require(foreach,doParallel,raster,rgdal)

    #Determine optimal block size for loading in MODIS stack data
    block_width = 15
    nrows = dim(stack_in)[1]
    nblocks <- nrows%/%block_width
    bs_rows <- seq(1,nblocks*block_width+1,block_width)
    bs_nrows <- rbind(matrix(block_width,length(bs_rows)-1,1),nrows-bs_rows[length(bs_rows)]+1)
    print('Working on the following rows')
    print(paste(bs_rows))

    #Register the parallel backend
    registerDoParallel(workers)

    result <- foreach(i = 1:length(bs_rows), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
      print(paste("Working on row",i))
      stack_values = getValues(stack_in, bs_rows[i], bs_nrows[i])
      return(FUN(stack_values))
     }

  stopImplicitCluster()
```

Hope this helps you get started.